Difference between Bernoulli Equation and Euler-Bernoulli Integral in Potential Flow
I want to solve the Euler equations for potential flow for some domain $M\in \mathbb{R}^3.$
So the Euler equations are
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf u=0\tag1$$
$$\rho\mathbf a=\rho\frac{D\mathbf u}{Dt}=\rho\mathbf f- \nabla  p \tag2$$
Or if we substitute the $F=-\nabla U$
$$\rho\frac{\partial  \mathbf u }{\partial t}+\rho\mathbf{u}\cdot (\nabla\mathbf u ) =-\nabla (\rho g h) - \nabla p $$
Now since I want to derive the governing equation for potential flow I substitute the potential flow definition:
$$\mathbf u =\nabla \varphi$$
The equations now become
$$\rho\frac{\partial   }{\partial t}\nabla \varphi+\rho \nabla \varphi\cdot \nabla (\nabla \varphi)= - \nabla (\rho g h) - \nabla p$$
$$\rho\frac{\partial   }{\partial t}\nabla \varphi+\rho\nabla \left( \frac{1}{2} |\nabla \varphi|^2 \right)=-\nabla (\rho g h) - \nabla p $$
$$\rho\frac{\partial   }{\partial t}\nabla \varphi+\rho \nabla \left( \frac{1}{2} |\mathbf u|^2 \right)+\nabla (\rho g h) + \nabla p  =0$$
$$\nabla\left( \rho\frac{\partial \varphi  }{\partial t} + \rho \frac{1}{2} |\mathbf u|^2 +\rho g h + p\right)=0$$
Or after integrating:
$$ \rho\frac{\partial \varphi  }{\partial t} +  \rho \frac{1}{2} |\mathbf u|^2 +\rho g h+  p=f(t)$$
Also, for stationary state we get
$$ \frac{\rho |\mathbf u|^2}{2} + \rho g h + p=C\tag3$$
This last equation $(3)$ is what I wanted to obtain.
My questions are as follows:

I heard that this equation differs from the standard Bernoulli equation because the Bernoulli equation is valid only for a single fluid streamline, but this equation holds for any path between any two points in $M$. Is that true? Is it because the potential and stationary state assumption, so the whole domain is of equal walue $C$?

Does this equation have a name? Is it the same as the Bernoulli equation? I heard of the name Euler-Bernoulli integral but I couldnt find any reference.



This is one form of Bernoulli's theorems for incomprensibile fluids. With slightly different assumptions, you get slightly different expressions. For compressible fluids, Bernoulli's theorems is derived starting from energy equation and not from momentum, and the conservation principle contains energy as well

BTW there was a typo in your question. I edited. BTW #2, you need irrotational flow to set $\mathbf{u} = \nabla \varphi$.

@basics Thanks for the fix. As for the second BTW, aren't potential flow and irrotational flow synonyms?

Yes, they are. But you need that the fluid must be irrotational in the problem you're modeling, to get reasonable results from this set of equations.

@basics Ok thanks.  So I can use it for any path between 2 points in the domain? And on the name of that equation when it is derived from the Euler equations, does there exist an Euler-Bernoulli integral in the literature or should I just call it the Bernoulli equation?

I'd call it just Bernoulli's theorem. You can use it for any pair of points in the same domain where the assumptions hold. As an example, you can't use it to connect two regions separated by rotational regions, like boundary layers or wakes. If needed, I'll add extra details tomorrow. Quite late here in Italy

@basics Thank you very much. If you want you can write an answer and I would gladly accept it, but you don't have to, you explained it all through the comments.

Check out for example the Feynman Lectures

From the comments I conclude:
First let's write the Euler momentum equation as ($\mathbf v$ instead $\mathbf u$ for velocity)
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq:II:40:6}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} + (\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{v} = -\frac{\nabla p}{\rho} - \nabla \phi,
\end{equation}
using $
(\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{v} = (\nabla \times \mathbf{v}) \times \mathbf{v} + \frac{1}{2} \nabla (\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v})$
We can write the equation of motion as
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq:II:40:8}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{\Omega} \times \mathbf{v} + \frac{1}{2} \nabla v^2 = -\frac{\nabla p}{\rho} - \nabla \phi.
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{\Omega} = \nabla \times \mathbf{v}$ is vorticity
Now to derive the Bernoulli's theorem we have 2 choices
1. With vorticity (more general)
We take the dot product with $\mathbf v$ of both sides
$$\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v} \cdot \left( \mathbf{\Omega} \times \mathbf{v} \right) + \mathbf{v} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \nabla v^2 = \mathbf{v} \cdot \left( -\frac{\nabla p}{\rho} - \nabla \phi \right)
\end{equation}
$$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \nabla v^2 = \mathbf{v} \cdot \left( -\nabla \left( \frac{p}{\rho} + \phi \right) \right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \left( \frac{p}{\rho} + \phi + \frac{1}{2} v^2 \right) = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq:II:40:13}
\frac{p}{\rho} + \frac{1}{2} v^2 + \phi = \text{const} \quad (\text{streamline}).
\end{equation}
So that equation is valid only for a single streamline.

No vorticity (potential flow)

Now if we immediately take $\mathbf \Omega =0$
we immediately get
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq:II:40:14}
\frac{p}{\rho} + \frac{1}{2} v^2 + \phi = \text{const} \quad (\text{everywhere}).
\end{equation}
So they are both variations of Bernoulli theorem but the last equation that is irrotational i.e. potential flow governs on the whole domain on where the assumptions hold.

What happens in case 2. when the flow happens in a torus-like region, with zero vorticity everywhere in the liquid, but there is no liquid at the center? This may happen if there is a vortex. The flow is not a potential flow...

$\varphi$ is just multivalued so we still speak of potential flow. Bernoulli's theorem holds on the entire space as $v,p$ are well defined (with the topological caveat that $C$ depends on the connected components it the domain is not connected)
